# Query with big IN clause

Tags: mysql, query-performance, amazon-rds

I'm having an performance issue with a query, the query is something like:

```
Select * 
from requests 
where start_date > {start_date} 
and end_date < {end_date} 
and employee in {employee_id_list}
```

The problem is that this employee list is huge, and come from another service and could contain up to 10.000 employee_id.

Are there any better way of doing this than using the employee_id_list as parameter for this query?

Comment: 1. What version of MySql 2. What is the primary key 3. What are any secondary indexes defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try use "with" clase

```
with employees as (
--- your employee list in select statement 
--- for example:
select 1 emp_id
union
select 2 
)

select * 
from requests rq
join employees em on (em.emp_id = rq.employee)
where start_date > {start_date} and end_date < {end_date}
```

Comment: I will try this out, I didn't knew this way could make any difference.

Comment: join is faster than in clause especially if you have unique list